# Finding a discrete distribution for the minimum number of times needed for all events to occur

Tags: distributions, uniform-distribution, coupon-collector-problem

Is there a distribution that describes the number of trials before all the events of a random variable with a discrete uniform distribution occurs?

Examples:

- The number of rolls before getting all the numbers on a die.
- The number of randomly chosen people needed to get a birthday every day of the year (excluding February 29th and assuming a discrete uniform distribution in birthdays)

Also, is there a generalized distribution to describe the number of times needed for all events to occur at least $K$ times?

Comment: You might want to start by looking into the Coupon Collector problem. There are several posts here on the topic, and there's a wikipedia page on it.

Comment: This question is practically the same as http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136714 (which is unanswered: I believe that's because a general answer would be messy).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a distribution that describes the number of trials before all the events of a random variable with a discrete uniform distribution occurs?

Yes, there is.  I call this distribution the **coupon collector's distribution**, since it describes the behaviour of the number of trials in the solution to the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).  The general form of the distribution and some of its properties are given here.

Let $X_1, X_2, X_3, ... \sim \text{IID U} \{ 1,...,m \}$ be uniformly distributed over $m \in \mathbb{N}$ categories and let $T$ be the smallest number of values in this series required to cover all the categories.  This random variable follows the coupon collector's distribution, which has mass function:

$$\mathbb{P}(T=t) = \frac{m!}{m^t} \cdot S(t-1, m-1) \quad \quad \quad \text{for all } t \geqslant m,$$

where the function $S$ denotes the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).  It can be shown that this distribution has [cumulant generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant):

$$K_T(s) = \ln((m+1)!) + sm + \sum_{r=0}^{m-1} \ln (m-re^s) \quad \quad \quad \text{for all } s \in \mathbb{R}.$$

Its mean and variance are given by:

$$\mathbb{E}(T) = m H_{1,m} \quad \quad \quad \mathbb{V}(T) = m^2 H_{2,m} - m H_{1,m} \quad \quad \quad H_{k,m} \equiv \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^k},$$

where the values $H_{k,m}$ are the [generalised harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalizations).  For large $m$ the harmonic numbers in the expression for the mean are often approximated by their asymptotic form to give $\mathbb{E}(T) \approx m (\gamma + \ln m)$ where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).  (The latter expression is sometimes incorrectly given as an exact expression for the mean.)

> Also, is there a generalized distribution to describe the number of times needed for all events to occur at least $K$ times.

Such a distribution certainly exists, but its form is quite complicated and cumbersome.  For this latter distribution it is usually simplest to deal with it by simulation (see e.g., [this answer to a related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136714/320277#320277)).